# Is there a way to copy Google Cloud Storage object from SDK Shell to network drive like Box?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to copy a GCS object via SDK Shell to a network drive like Box?

What i've tried is below. Thanks.

```
gsutil cp gs://your-bucket/some_file.tif C:/Users/Box/01. name/folder

CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command.
```

Comment: Are you running this command on Windows? If yes, the destination filename is either incorrect or you need to surround the path with quotes because of the space character in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a typo in your destination:

```
C:/Users/Box/01. name/folder
```

There is a space after the period and before 'name' - you'll need to either wrap it in quotes or escape that space. Looks like you're on Windows; [here's a doc](https://www.howtogeek.com/694949/how-to-escape-spaces-in-file-paths-on-the-windows-command-line/) on how to escape spaces in file paths.